# java, If Super class uses try/catch, Why can't the extending class override super class method with throws in method definition & Checked Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, checked, unchecked

Prog 1:
If we use Checked Exception the program fails to compile

Here Student class has a method "tt" which throws an exception ClassNotFoundException which is a checked exception in java.

The Test class extends Student class and overrides the method "tt". This time instead of using try/catch I am trying to use throws keyword.

The result is a compile-time failure.

```
class Student{

public void tt(){

    try {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {

    }
}
}
class Test extends Student {

public void tt() throws ClassNotFoundException{

}

}
```

Prog 2:
If we use Unchecked Exception the profile compiles and runs fine.

The same Student class has a method "tt" which throws an exception NullPointerException which is an unchecked exception in java.

The Test class extends Student class and overrides the method "tt". This time instead of using try/catch I am trying to use throws keyword.

The result is a successful run. The below program runs without any issues.

```
class Student{

public void tt(){

    try {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e) {

    }
}
}
class Test extends Student {

public void tt() throws NullPointerException{

}

}
```

Any leads is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why? Because the language specification says that an overriding method cannot declare exceptions that the overridden method didn’t declare. And because when I have a reference to a `Student` object and call `tt`, no try-catch is needed. Now if the actual object was a `Test`, what should happen? It’d be a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had this code:

```
Student s = new Test ();
s.tt ();
```

Since `tt` method of `Student` class has no `throws` clause, you are allowed to call `s.tt()` without handling any exceptions.

But if a sub-class of `Student` (`Test` in your case) overrides `tt` and throws a checked exception, the caller must handle that exception. But the caller doesn't know they have to handle it, since the base class has no throws clause. Therefore the sub-class is not allowed to add `throws` clauses of checked exceptions to the methods it overrides.

Comment: For such an obvious duplicate, wouldn’t it be better to close than to provide a new answer?

Comment: Hi Eran, Thanks for the prompt reply. But what would be the reason that it works with unchecked/Runtime Exceptions. Refer to Prog 2 in the question.

Comment: @PranavKumar unchecked exceptions don't have to be handled, so you are always free to throw them (since the caller doesn't have to know about them). In fact, you can throw the NullPointerException even if you remove the throws clause.

Comment: Because unchecked exceptions don’t need to be declared. From the method signature the method in the superclass could have thrown a `NullPointerException` too, so the subclass doesn’t introduce any new exception.

Answer (score -1):

Effective signature of method that is getting overridden must be same. Here effective means, change in return type, subclasses of thrown exception in method signature.

Comment: Except the subclass is allowed to declare fewer exception types. Only not introduce any.

Comment: This isn't true.  When overriding a method, it's perfectly fine to change the return type to a subtype, to remove exception types, or to replace exception types with subtypes.

Comment: I wrote the scope of effective. (Change in return type and about exceptions.)